# Twisted Python ESMTP mail server / dump with TLS

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, twisted

As some of you may have seen recently I was struggling to get a simple Client/Server TCP connection up and running, where I could switch to TLS on issue of a command, as per the Twisted example at https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/core/howto/ssl.html#starttls-server, but modified to use certificate authentication. Well, the good news is that now works! Thanks to @Jean-PaulCalderone and @Glyph for their help.

However I now want to extend / transform my server side code into an ESMTP server - ie, let the client connect, server then advertises STARTTLS as part of its EHLO response, and if the client then responds with STARTTLS, negotiate and switch to a secure connection. I *believe* I need to modify the "TLSServer" class in my server code below to be inherited from twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTP instead of twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver - but not 100% sure here. Moreover, the API docs for t.m.s.ESMTP as found at http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.1.0/api/twisted.mail.smtp.ESMTP.html are a little thin on the ground (lots of undocumented methods).

Can anyone a) tell me if I am right regarding modifing the inheritance of my existing server code, and b) offer up some explanation of methods such as do_EHLO and ext_STARTTLS?

Ultimately I am looking for an SMTP server that will accept (secured) client connections, receive a mail from the client, and dump the mail to file.

My existing server code:

```
from twisted.internet import ssl, protocol, defer, task, endpoints
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.python.modules import getModule
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_privatekey, load_certificate, FILETYPE_PEM

class TLSServer(LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print("received: " + line)
        if line == "STARTTLS":
            print("-- Switching to TLS")
            self.sendLine('READY')
            self.transport.startTLS(self.factory.options)

def main(reactor):
    caCertFile = open("/some/path/to/cacert.pem","r")
    certFile = open("/some/path/to/server.crt","r")
    keyFile = open("/some/path/to/server.key","r")
    caCertData = caCertFile.read()
    pKeyData = keyFile.read()
    certData = certFile.read()
    caCert = ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(caCertData)
    cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, certData)
    pKey = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, pKeyData)
    factory = protocol.Factory.forProtocol(TLSServer)
    factory.options = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=pKey, certificate=cert, trustRoot=caCert)
    endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8000)
    endpoint.listen(factory)
    return defer.Deferred()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import starttls_server
    task.react(starttls_server.main)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac might be interesting

Comment: Quite possibly... Can you advise, how to override the default server responses - eg, replacing the 220 response when a client connects, or the 250 responses to an EHLO from the client?

Comment: Some of those things can be customized by overridding methods of `ESMTP`.  For example, there's the `greeting` method for the text of the 220 message.  To be able to override other things, you might need to file feature requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have your own `TLSServer` class.  Instead, just use `ESMTP` directly as your server class.  You've already identified the `ext_STARTTLS` method as interesting - basically, it already implements the logic that your `TLSServer` has in its `lineReceived` method.

Rather than doing `factory.options = ...`, you will want to pass `ESMTP` a `contextFactory` argument upon construction.  At the simplest, you could do something like this:

```
sslCtxFactory = ssl.CertificateOptions(...)
factory = Factory.forProtocol(lambda: ESMTP(contextFactory=sslCtxFactory))
```

I *believe* that `ESMTP` advertises `STARTTLS` as an extension by default - at least, that's what a quick reading of the implementation of `ESMTP.extensions()` method says to me.

Comment: Thanks again @Glyph - we're now well underway getting the tweaks / customisations we need in place!